# Can't install Internet Explorer for Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer

I'm using Windows 7 64-bit.

My IE crashes when starting, so I tried to reinstall. I downloaded `IE11-Windows6.1.exe` from the MS site. But when I run it, it says

[image]

That's odd. I thought IE11 was the latest version for Win7. (I don't remember which version I have and I can't check since it won't start.) I tried "Control Panel" | "Programs and Features" to see if I could uninstall IE, but it isn't listed there. Revo Uninstaller doesn't list it either.

How can I reinstall or repair IE?

**edit**
upon request: IE11_main.log:

```
00:00.000: ====================================================================  
00:00.015: Started: 2013/12/15 (Y/M/D) 16:07:36.224 (local)
00:00.015: Time Format in this log: MM:ss.mmm (minutes:seconds.milliseconds)
00:00.015: Command line: "D:\Software\Web\IE\IE11-Windows6.1.exe" 
00:00.015: INFO:    Setup installer for Internet Explorer: 11.0.9600.16428
00:00.015: INFO:    Previous version of Internet Explorer: 11.0.9600.16428
00:00.015: INFO:    Checking if iexplore.exe's current version is between 11.0.9600.0...
00:00.015: INFO:    ...and 11.1.0.0...
00:00.015: INFO:    Maximum version on which to run IEAK branding is: 11.1.0.0...
00:00.015: ERROR:   A newer version of Internet Explorer is already installed on the system.
00:00.015: ERROR:   Internet Explorer version check failed.
00:11.575: INFO:    Setup exit code: 0x00009C48 (40008) - A more recent version of Internet Explorer is installed.
00:11.669: INFO:    Cleaning up temporary files in: C:\Windows\TEMP\IE18783.tmp
00:11.669: INFO:    Unable to remove directory C:\Windows\TEMP\IE18783.tmp, marking for deletion on reboot.
00:11.684: INFO:    Released Internet Explorer Installer Mutex
```

Apparently 11.0.9600.16428 is not between 11.0.9600.0 and 11.1.0.0? :-/

Comment: What version did you have installed before the crashes started to happen.  Try loading Ie in safe mode if that fails to work start uninstalling the most recent software you have installed since the crashes happen of that fails use a recovery point

Comment: there should be an IE11main.log in the Windows directory. Upload this log.

Comment: @Ramhound: he says he can't check the version, so I think he doesn't know.

Comment: My suggestion? "Just use Chrome or Firefox"

Comment: @JanDvorak: I am using Firefox. I wanted to see what my website looks like in IE...

Comment: Then I guess http://netrenderer.com/ should do

Comment: @JanDvorak: Thanks for that link. Seems to have problems though: since yesterday it shows a banner for PC restart. Also this shows what it looks like (granted, that's what I asked for in my previous comment), but doesn't tell you about interactivity: it appears my page *looks* OK in IE8, but the Javascript doesn't work.